# django rest framework url arguments with patch not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Edit**

I suspect the whole problem with my UpdateApiView is with the url. No matter how I change it, will return 404.

```
url(r'verify-phone/(?P<phone_id>^\d+)$', view.VerifyPhone.as_view(), name='verify-phone'),
```

it returns

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}


[18/Apr/2016 01:39:02] "PATCH /api/verify-phone/phone_id=00980 HTTP/1.1" 404 4941
```

Why?

views.py

```
class VerifyPhone(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = serializers.VerifyPhoneSerializer
    allowed_methods = ['PATCH']
    lookup_field = 'phone_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        phone_id = self.request.query_params.get('phone_id', None)
        queryset = User.objects.filter(phone_id=phone_id)
        return queryset

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('inside update')
    print(request.data)
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    print(instance)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    print(serializer)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    print('done perform update')
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class VerifyPhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regex = r'\d+'
    verification_code = serializers.RegexField(regex, max_length=7, min_length=7, allow_blank=False)
    phone_id = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='verify-phone', lookup_field='phone_id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('verification_code', 'phone_id')

    def validate(self, data):
        verification = api.tokens.verify(data['phone_id'], data['verification_code'])

        if verification.response.status_code != 200:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid verification code.")

        return data

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.phone_number_validated = True
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

---

> Second question Is this correct to get phone_id from the views?

```
phone_id = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='verify-phone', lookup_field='phone_id', read_only=True)
```

Comment: i just deleted the whole view in this question. Can you go look at the history? The reason I deleted the whole code is because it's unnecessary. But will add if you think so.

Comment: and why do you down voted this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your api url def, I think you should call:

```
/api/verify-phone/00980
```

instead of

```
/api/verify-phone/phone_id=00980
```

---

I also think something is wrong with the url def itself (the ^ before \d):

```
url(r'verify-phone/(?P<phone_id>^\d+)$', view.VerifyPhone.as_view(), name='verify-phone')
```

should be

```
url(r'verify-phone/(?P<phone_id>\d+)$', view.VerifyPhone.as_view(), name='verify-phone')
```

or

```
url(r'verify-phone/(?P<phone_id>\d{5})$', view.VerifyPhone.as_view(), name='verify-phone')
```

Comment: So? Was it the issue?

Comment: it wasn't the issue. The problem was entirely different thing that I wasn't aware of at that time and the question is not related at all. I'll accept anyway for your good effort to help :).